# “Is there an Access SQL code/query for concatenating first letter plus a unique ID number and insert into a new column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

First of all, I am quite new to SQL and Microsoft Access.

I am setting a database in Access. My database collects information from four different departments. I store my data through forms. My main table (Business) stores information (department) using a Combo Box saving a number instead of text.

I want to have a column (similar to CODE ID already available in the table above) which shows the initial letter from a field (name Department) + a number.

Ie. In table "Business", I want to display a Code ID which contains the initials of column Department plus a number code (department order number ascending). I want to have this every time i add information.

```
+===============+=================+=========+==+
|  DEPARTMENT   |     PARTNER     | CODE ID |  |
+===============+=================+=========+==+
| Data_Analysis | John Doe        | D001    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
| Marketing     | Jane Doe        | M001    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
| Finance       | Alex Mustermann | F001    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
| Operations    | Juan Perez      | O001    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
| Finance       | Barack Trump    | F002    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
| Finance       | Mark Merkel     | F003    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
| Marketing     | Peggy Hilton    | M002    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
| Operations    | Max Mustermann  | O002    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
| Operations    |                 | OXXX    |  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------+--+
```

The values in column CODE ID are those I would like to have display every time I add a new row (new department order). I need this type of code for tracking my number of orders in each department and use it as a unique code for any inquires with partners. I dont want to have it as the primary key id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which mysql version you are using?

Comment: ' setting a database in Access'  so where does mysql come into it?

Comment: Are you using mysql (as tagged and stated in the title), or ms-access (as explained in the text)?

Comment: You guys are real quick. I wanna to establish a unique field in a column that contains: "initial word from field in Column A" + "number Order". First time sharing here, hope is all fine!

Comment: Use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to provide sample data and expected result. Not images.

Answer (score 0):

If you rethink the schema slightly it becomes trivial; instead of having the column with the ID and code combined, just keep a running count when inserting:

```
INSERT INTO business(department, name, code) SELECT Forms!Department, Forms!Name, COUNT(*)+1 FROM business WHERE name=Forms!Name
```

Then when you pull the information out:

```
SELECT department, name, LEFT(1, department) & code
```

Comment: This will show the same count for every person in a department. OP wants a running sum.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher after i index information from the department and partner, i wanna display the code (initial letter department + number of order in the department) in a new column.

Comment: @RomuloCardenas Does this answer show your expected result?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I re-read it and I came to the conclusion that you're right, and I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: @LTPCGO this can be done by query. See https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=274257

Comment: @LTPCGO i might have adressed the question wrong. The fields in column CODE ID shown in the Table Business, should be automatically generated when I place information in column Department.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher my edited post should do the same, the order of these are a bit of a mess as there have been edits to the initial question changing the scope somewhat

Comment: @RomuloCardenas you could combine the column in but it's going make it much harder and messier, there is no clear reason why the SELECT query wouldn't work; if you can give your usage case I can edit it appropriately

Comment: @LTPCGO: as OP now specified, CodeID should be generated after new department has been choosen, so an update query would fit better if he wants to store CodeID. But CodeID could also be computed in a query, what you almost archived in your former solution (see my link above for help).

Comment: @LTPCGO thank you very much for your effort. As previously mentioned, I want to generate a code right after I place information in column Department. The code should contain the initials of the department + the order number within department. This code would be unique for each order (emails, storage, etc)